# No sound after merging two videos using melt tool

Tags: media-player, mlt, melt-framework

I am using melt tool to merge videos. It merges videos but in the output file sound is missing. Bot video1.mp4 and video2.mp4 have sound so I would expect output file to have it too. Could somebody help me which additional option should I use?

```
melt video1.mp4 video2.mp4 -consumer avformat:outputvodep.mp4 acodec=libmp31ame vcodec=libx264
```

Answer (score 0):

`libmp31ame` is not a valid audio codec because you misspelled it. It should `libmp3lame` (assuming the FFmpeg build to which MLT is linked was configured to build with lame).